# Projection and positive element in C$^*$-algebras

Tags: c-star-algebras, banach-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let ‎$‎‎A$ ‎be ‎a‎ ‎$‎‎C^*$-algebra, ‎$‎‎p\in A$  a ‎‎projection.

‎‎‎
Assume ‎that ‎‎$‎‎a$ ‎is  a element in ‎$‎‎ \text{Ball}(A_+)$ ‎such ‎that  ‎‎$‎‎a‎\leq p‎$‎.

> Q: May I‎ ‎say ‎‎$‎‎ap=pa$? Why?‎
>   ‎

Answer (score 3):

You have
$$
0\leq(1-p)a(1-p)\leq(1-p)p(1-p)=0. 
$$
Thus $$0=(1-p)a(1-p)=(a^{1/2}(1-p))^*(a^{1/2}(1-p)),$$
and $a^{1/2}(1-p)=0$, from where $a(1-p)=0$; so $a=ap$. Taking adjoints, $a=pa$. If follows that $a=pap$.